# I was able to run Ubuntu from the LIVE CD on an ASUS Windows 8 Touch screen Laptop. However when I take the CD out I am not able to boot into Windows

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8

I used this method

[Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system).

I followed the process as described by Luis

The Live CD installation works, I can see the my data that was under Windows 8, however I am not able to boot into Windows 8. When I remove the CD.

Comment: Firstly, it is recommended on the Ubuntu UEFI wiki page to disable Secure Boot before installing (all Win 8 machines have Secure Boot enabled by default). Did you change the boot mode to "Legacy" or "BIOS" before you did the installation? Do you see a GRUB menu to select your OS and Windows isn't there, or is there no menu at all?

Comment: @Githlar - On my laptop, the ubuntu iso / DVD / flash drive will not boot unless secure boot is disabled. OP can boot Ubuntu, so, although it is possibly a problem with secure boot, less likely in my experience.

Comment: However, if he changed the boot mode to "Legacy" or "CSM" then Ubuntu will have installed GRUB on the MBR rather than ESP. This would mean that MBR-GRUB will only allow you to boot Ubuntu until you add a rule to /etc/default/grub

Comment: @Githlar, I have changed boot mode to CSM.

Comment: So Ubuntu installed MBR-based Grub since you booted it with CSM. Your BIOS is also set to boot using the legacy MBR partitioning (because of the CSM), which means it only shows GRUB and GRUB only shows Linux. If you change it back to EFI/UEFI mode by disabling CSM you should only be able to boot Windows. The only real fix to this is to disable CSM and re-install Ubuntu in EFI mode. Please see the [Ubuntu Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) about the steps you need to take to ensure a smooth installation.

Comment: I want to have a dual boot option. The original instruction did suggest that I disable CSM. I shall start the process again, I have time to play, could you guide to a specific link. I will now start with reformatted and Windows 8 reinstalled Asus laptop with touch

Answer (score 0):

IMO the easiest method is boot repair

[image]

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
```

Hit enter to allow the installation.

```
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
```

Use "Recommended repair"

Post the url it gives you if you have problems

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair for details

Comment: If you read the post that he linked, this is part of the process he used to get Ubuntu installed, so it's assumed he already did this.